How to Delete image picker library created folder form mobile device
While using image picker. after cropping image how to delete the folder created by image picker from android app storage? because this folders increase apps data size.
i tried by calling image picker method getAllFile() but this method always return null. Could you please help me out..

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
